# Change default collation for NVARCHAR columns in MariaDb 10.6

Tags: database, mariadb, collation

I'm stuck with a problem in MariaDb 10.6.4, which I didn't encounter in 10.5.12.

I set the default character set and default collation for my database (and actually for my server) to utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_general_ci.
Though the server setting doesn't affect the defaults for information_schema, performance_schema and sys in 10.6.4 (they are still utf8mb3), all other databases which I create having utf8mb4.

I use `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME, DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA` to verify the default settings.

[image: default_schemas]

I use the following Sql to create a test table on the database ETLBox_DataFlow2

```
CREATE TABLE testtable
(
    col1 NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(100)  NULL,
    col3 VARCHAR(100) COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    col4 VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
)
```

When I check the character set & collation that each column uses, I see that the NVARCHAR column still has utf8mb3 as default character set.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
FROM information_schema.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'testtable'
```

[image: table_columns_collations]

This is very unfortunate, as I use C# and the latest MySql connector 8.0 to retrieve data from this table. But the connector won't work with data collated in utf8mb3, as this is already deprecated by MySql/Oracle.

I never had this issue with MariaDb 10.5.12. I know that MariaDb changed the default for utf8, but I thought that now everything would be aligned to utf8mb4 to be in line with MySql. I tried to play around with the @@OLD_MODE, but didn't see any differences here when creating the table.

Is there a way to change this behaviour? I would like that also NVARCHAR columns are collated to utf8mb4 by default (or actually any other collation than utf8mb3 would work for me).

Looking forward to your replies!